# How to pass properties from grandchild menu object to grandparent?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

my employer decided to expand the menu bar with another sub-pages, and things that works completely fine previously (simple one sub-menu) now don't want to work, because it has sub-menu, under another sub-menu.
Here is the pics:

[image]

As you can see when I hover "Acts" the sub menu with External and Internal documents works perfectly fine
[image]

but when I would like to move cursor on another sub-menu with "Director's Orders", whole menu is hiding. I think it's because second sub-menu (grandchild) don't pass info to main menu element (grandparent) to keep menu active, but I have no idea how to fix it.
Here is the code:

```
<v-menu open-on-hover bottom offset-x transition="slide-x-transition">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-list-item link v-on="on">
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title class="subtitle-1">Acts <v-icon class="menu-icon">keyboard_arrow_right</v-icon></v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      </template>
          <v-list color="#F0FAFE">
            <router-link to="/External"><v-list-item link>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title class="subtitle-1 font-weight-medium">External</v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item></router-link>
            <v-menu open-on-hover bottom offset-x transition="slide-x-transition">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-list-item link v-on="on">
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title class="subtitle-1 font-weight-medium">Internal <v-icon class="menu-icon">keyboard_arrow_right</v-icon></v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
            </template>
              <v-list color="#F0FAFE">
                <v-menu open-on-hover bottom offset-x transition="slide-x-transition">
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                  <v-list-item link v-on="on">
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title class="subtitle-1 font-weight-medium">Director's Orders <v-icon class="menu-icon">keyboard_arrow_right</v-icon></v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item>
                </template>
                  <v-list
                  color="#F0FAFE"
                  v-for="(item, index) in Orders"
                  :key="index"
                  >
                    <router-link :to="'/' + item.title"><v-list-item link>
                      <v-list-item-content>
                        <v-list-item-title class="subtitle-1 font-weight-medium">{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                      </v-list-item-content>
                    </v-list-item></router-link>
                  </v-list>
                </v-menu>
                <router-link to="/Other"><v-list-item link>
                  <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title class="subtitle-1 font-weight-medium">Other</v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item-content>
                </v-list-item></router-link>
              </v-list>
            </v-menu>
          </v-list>
      </v-menu>
```

*And little disclaimer. Yes I know this type of menu isn't a Material Design menu, which is the base for vuetify*

Comment: Either use vuex or have the child emit an event to the parent, who will then emit an event to the grandparent and pass the data along. Or if grandparent contains the grandchild, then just have the grandparent listen for an event on child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think v-menu supports nested menus (at least not when opening them with mouseover).

You'd have to make one yourself with nested v-hover. You can create a recursive component building the menu from a nested array of items.

Something like this:

```
<template>
  <v-list color="#F0FAFE" class="menu">
    <v-hover v-for="item in items" :key="item.title" v-slot="{ hover }">
      <router-link v-if="item.route" :to="item.route" class="item">
        <v-list-item link>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </router-link>
      <v-list-item v-else class="item">
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }} -&gt;</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>

        <NestedMenu v-if="item.children && hover" :items="item.children"/>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-hover>
  </v-list>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "NestedMenu",
  props: {
    items: { type: Array, default: () => [] }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is a working example (which need some styling tho): https://codesandbox.io/s/nestedmenu-u8tk1?file=/src/components/NestedMenu.vue

Add more items and levels on menuItems in App.vue.